# Makefile for a C++ SDL project

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm still learning how to set up a `Makefile` and I'm kind of lost here. I'm using windows and currently trying to fire up my `Makefile` for small C++ SDL project.

I have 3 .cpp files:

```
main.cpp
window.cpp
rect.cpp
```

As well as 2 extra header files:

```
Window.h
rect.h
```

So having trouble setting up everything on a `Makefile` 
This is what i currently have:

```
CXXFLAGS = -Ideps/include -std=c++0x
LXXFLAGS = -Ldeps/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

cup: main.o
    g++ main.o -o cup $(LXXFLAGS) 

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ main.cpp -c $(CXXFLAGS) 

window.o: window.cpp 
    g++ window.cpp -c 

rect.o: rect.cpp 
    g++ rect.cpp -c
```

But I'm getting a bunch of undefined reference errors for my constructors on my command prompt. 
Help please!

Comment: Can you share the errors you are getting?

Comment: Instead of writing Makefiles directly I highly recommend using `CMake` right from the beginning. It's a higher level build tool that generates the `Makefile` from your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

From the Makefile contents I read that `cup` binary is only created from `main.o` and it does not link `window.o` nor `rect.o`, which is where probably those missing references are defined. At the very least I would update the primary rule to say:

```
cup: main.o window.o rect.o
    g++ $(LXXFLAGS) -o cup $^
```

Thus said, you could make even more use from implicit rules that are built into `make`, and, if following the standard naming for linking flags, the `Makefile` could be reduced even further to just a linking line (as compilation rules are implicit), e.g.:

```
$ cat Makefile
CXXFLAGS = -Ideps/include -std=c++0x
LDFLAGS = -Ldeps/lib
LDLIBS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2

cup: main.o window.o rect.o
        $(LINK.cc) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

Output:

```
$ make
g++ -Ideps/include -std=c++0x   -c -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -Ideps/include -std=c++0x   -c -o window.o window.cpp
g++ -Ideps/include -std=c++0x   -c -o rect.o rect.cpp
g++ -Ideps/include -std=c++0x  -Ldeps/lib  main.o window.o rect.o -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -o cup
```